# Why is ${\rm Div} E =0$?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, gauss-law

I understand that Div E for a charged body, takes the value of the volume charge density, inside the sphere.
Why is it 0, outside the sphere, then? 
Because, with distance, it does decrease, isn't it? (Inverse square law)

Or, how else should it be thought of?

Answer (score 3):

Intuitively, the divergence of the field tells you how much each little point in space acts like a tiny "source" or "sink" (or better, an *emanator*) for that field. Note here two things:

1. Emanation of electric field is what charges, and *only* charges, do. This is the point of Gauss's law involving the divergence. We have never found any region of space to emanate electric field without charge, and if we did, we could also just as well say that means charge is present there by definition.
2. The divergence measures the emanation *at a tiny point in space*. Not an extended region - if there is some charge sitting some distance away from the point in question, the emanation is from "over there". It is not from the point "here" that we are looking at.

In your example, all the charge is presumed to be inside the sphere. Outside the sphere, even a tiny, but nonzero, distance away, there is no charge. Since the divergence tells you how much emanation is occurring *at a point* only, then since each point outside that sphere has no charge located there, there can be no emanation of electric field at that point. Hence $\nabla \cdot \mathbf{E} = 0$. Conversely, if this equation holds true at a point, that means there is no charge present there. So the converse is a statement that there is no charge present at any point outside the charged sphere.

Comment: So, if we think of a point outside the sphere, can we tell that the sum of the flux 'emanating' from the point=0?

Comment: @Swaroop Joshi : Exactly. If the point is outside, there should be no emanation from it because there's no charge there to do the emanating.

Answer (score 0):

The divergence of the E-field is a property that applies to a point in space. If there is no net charge density at that point, then the divergence is zero.

Comment: So, if we think of a point outside the charged sphere, can we tell that the sum of the flux 'emanating' from the point=0?

Comment: @SwaroopJoshi divergence is the net flux out of a closed surface per unit volume. So, yes.

Answer (score 0):

When you think about the specific example of the point charge, the **Electric Field** is obtained by $E = \frac{kq}{r^{2}}$, that's the inverse square law. What you are asking is **why the divergence of E at a specific point is zero, even though the electric field generated by another source is not.** That happens because of the definition of divergence, it tells you whether a specific point of space is "emanating" or "absorbing" determined quantity.

When we calculate $div(E)$ we are actually trying to know whether there are more electric field lines going inward or outward from that point. If that's positive, we conveniently say it's outward. If that's negative, we conveniently say it's inward.

The tricky part is that you need to understand that electric field lines are just **generated** by charges, and inside the sphere, there is no charge. Therefore, even though **the electric field generated by the sphere in all space** affects the point you are trying to analyze, **there is no electric field being generated from that point**.